# Handling 404 in resolve with angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a service with a method:

```
service.getVenueBySlug = function(slug) {
    return $http.get(API + '/venue/' + slug);
};
```

In my app.routes.js`:

```
.state('app.venue', {
  url: '/venues/:venueSlug',
  templateUrl: '/app/views/venue.html',
  controller: 'VenueController',
  resolve: {
    venue: ['VenueService', '$stateParams', '$state', function (VenueService, $stateParams, $state) {
      return VenueService.getVenueBySlug($stateParams.venueSlug).then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      }).catch(function(err) {
        $state.go('app.404');
      });
    }]
  }
})
```

The controller `VenueController` simply has:

`$scope.venue = venue`

Everything is working and it's correctly redirecting to 404 if I manually go to an URL with a wrong venue slug.

The issue is that I'm receiving an error in the console that it's bothering me:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix? I'm using angular 1.6.4 and angular-ui-router 1.0.6.

Comment: use  npm update angular-ui-router to update ui router, may be it resolved your issue

Comment: Probably you should to reject promise. (return $q.reject())

Comment: @PetrAveryanov reject where?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment to your post - in your resolve's catch, you probably should do something in the lines of: return $q.reject({redirectTo: app.404});

Then in your router config you listen to stateChangeErrors:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
   function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
      if(error.redirectTo) {
         $state.go(error.redirectTo);
      }
   } 
})
```

the $q.reject is required to handle (interrupt) the current stateChange, and the stateChangeError is there to handle that reject.

(haven't tested the code but I remember having a similar solution in one of my projects)

Comment: Thanks. What's the different between using `$stateChangeError` and `$state.defaultErrorHandler`?

Comment: defaultErrorHandler is an addition in 1.0. They serve the same purpose. You can register your function that your route errors will be passed to in an app.run for example. 

Reading up on the breaking changes however, from the docs migration guide: "All state events, (i.e. $stateChange* and friends) are now deprecated and disabled by default". 
https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0


So if you're using 1.0, use defaultErrorHandler